# Different ways of initializing an object inside of a structure

Tags: c++, qt, clang, c++20

I have following class:

```
// NetworkManager.hpp
class NetworkManager : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    NetworkManager(QHostAddress const& address, quint16 port);

private:
    QHostAddress const& _address;
    quint16 const _port;
};

// NetworkManager.cpp
NetworkManager(QHostAddress const& address, quint16 const port)
    : _address(address)
    , _port(port)
{
}
```

This class included in a structure:

```
struct Context {
    NetworkManager networkManager
};
```

I initialize this structure like this:

```
class A {
public:
    A() : _context({{QHostAddress::SpecialAddress::LocalHost, 1337}})
    {
    }

private:
    Context _context;
};
```

The problem is when the structure is getting initialized, it calls NetworkManager copy constructor, which is deleted by default, because it inherits QObject. But when I use different initialization, `_context{{QHostAddress::SpecialAddress::LocalHost, 1337}}`, everything works fine. Why does it happen?

I use Clang compiler and C++20 standard.

Comment: Too many brackets in the first case, which is making it create a temporary object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code example is constructing a temporary object which then gets passed to `_context`'s copy constructor.

`_context({{QHostAddress::SpecialAddress::LocalHost, 1337}})`
is basically the same as

```
Context temp(QHostAddress::SpecialAddress::LocalHost, 1337);
Context _context(temp);
```

The second example,
`_context{{QHostAddress::SpecialAddress::LocalHost, 1337}}`
is constructing the _context object in place, no temporary is created so no copy is performed.

Comment: Should I always use the second initialization then?

Comment: @Mark You should decide what you want your code to do, and then write the code to do that. Like, if you don't want a temporary object and copy constructor call, don't write code which does that. I can't think of a situation where you would want it, but there is probably some use case where it might make sense.